# Can anyone tell me if I can tell if the profile is verified by PSID?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble getting information from users on facebook. Can anyone tell me if I can tell if the profile is verified by PSID?

Comment: Are you talking about `verified`, or `is_verified`?

Comment: Don’t think which type of ID you use to access the info should matter. But you might simply lack the permission to get that info, if you just got the PSID and the user did not log in to your app to grant it access to their personal info?